# Play movie using MPMoviePlayerController in landscape ONLY - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape-portrait

My app requires portrait orientation. everything is working great. Now I want to add an intro video when app is launched first time.

I have successfully added the video and everything. but **I want to play just the video in Landscape mode only, after video ends, my app should work in portrait mode.**

I googled and found some answers but do not get them working. Please suggest how can I achieve this, or I need to use some other movie controller?

This is how I have added the movie player:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp4"];
                NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
                self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
                [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(introMovieFinished:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                           object:self.moviePlayerController];

                // Hide the video controls from the user
                [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

                [self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

                [self.view insertSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view atIndex:10];

                [self.moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this before you play video**

```
 NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

**When video is finished or in Done button pressed**

```
  NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

This will play video in **Landscape** only, after completion View will back to **Portrait.**